# Create 1 image from masked image in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, image-masking

I have a image and i mask this image with another image to make shape.

I just want to change the view background color of Masked image.

I am using `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:maskedImage];`

But its not working.

Please suggest me how to merge or create Masked 2 images in 1 image so `colorWithPatternImage` will work.

Comment: Is it a pattern? Create a bitmap image context, clip the context to your mask, draw image, create image from your bitmap context

Comment: Actually for the Painting i am creating the mask image to paint in shape only After painting done i have one another view with same blank image so i have to change that image color with painted image.

Comment: Show your code. Otherwise, there's no way to know why it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UIImage *originalImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"original.png"]; //my background image
UIImage *maskedImage       = [UIImage imageNamed:@"maskedImage.png"]; //my masked image

CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );


[originalImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];


[maskedImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:0.6];

UIImage *newMaskedBackGroundImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

then use this newMaskedBackGroundImage, 
ex. `[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:newMaskedBackGroundImage];`

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning the value of

```
 [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:maskedImage];
```

to anything?  Like...

```
  self.maskedView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:maskedImage];
```